# Win32::OLE::Const can't find 64-bit MS Office constants

Tags: windows, perl, ms-office, ole, win32ole

We have a legacy `perl` code base that includes the below line:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
```

This has worked traditionally but is not working on newer 64-bit installations, such as Windows 10.

The error appears to be in the `OLE.xs` source as below, but I have a limited understanding of Windows functions and `XS` in general.

```
err = RegQueryValueA(hKeyLangid, "win32", szFile, &cbFile);
```

If this query fails, it never calls `Win32::OLE::Const::_Typelib` which is the function that stores the result. Checking my registry, the keys are indeed `Win64` and not `win32`. Other keys that worked either have just `win32` or both.

**Is there a way to resolve this issue without editing the legacy module?** It is widely used and any changes would involve some risk so I'm looking at alternatives first.

I'm aware we can do the below, but it doesn't stop the other `Win32::OLE::Const` line causing an error if it's not removed.

```
my $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');
my $xl = Win32::OLE::Const->Load($Excel);
```

Comment: I do not see how to achieve that without changing the source code, given the value is hard coded. XS is perl's interface to call C/C++ code, btw.

I cannot help myself, I've got to point out that the module is literally called 'Win32::OLE', so I don't know why you'd expect it to work on 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509960/how-to-make-win32ole-work-on-64bit-ms-office-installation

That seems like a simple workaround not requiring you to change the module, fwiw.

Comment: @bytepusher agreed that's the exact issue. So if adding the registry key is safe, then I guess we'll have to go down that path and roll out a patch to all our machines.

Comment: well if the fix is only to replace the registry key - how about you put win64::OLE on cpan :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a fix in case anyone wants to use it. It's not clear to me whether `Win32::OLE` is still being maintained, as the issues list at https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=48858 raised this exact item a number of months ago, so I'm not sure where to submit a patch.

As noted in that link there are a few ways to resolve this (such as giving preference to the `win64` entry if both exist), however I've decided it would be best in our case to only query the `win64` folder if `win32` does not return anything useful.

To do this, in `OLE.xs` search for `win32` and change as below.

```
err = RegQueryValueA(hKeyLangid, "win32", szFile, &cbFile);

// check win64 if win32 failed
if (err != ERROR_SUCCESS || cbFile <= 1)
    err = RegQueryValueA(hKeyLangid, "win64", szFile, &cbFile);
```